# Save Matrix values when values change from NaN to a Number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have a 3x15000 matrix and I want to save the segments during a change from NaN to a number. So I have large sections that all 3 rows are NaN and when it changes I want to generate a new matrix. Is it best to index the start and end point? How do I set a flag in order to step through all the data?

For example:

`NaN    5.30669473796592    5.82479888441640 NaN 
 NaN    103.308010031436    103.534581233064 NaN
 NaN    1787365.55338272    1745186.16219408 NaN`

So I want to save the numeric values inbetween.

Comment: could you provide a small example with the desired output you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct me if I am wrong, but it sounds like that 3x15000 matrix of yours contains some discrete data and you want to save each chunk of data as an individual matrix.

Suppose your matrix looks like this:

```
h(:,[2,3,5]) = rand(3,3)

h =

   NaN    0.9649    0.9572       NaN    0.1419       NaN
   NaN    0.1576    0.4854       NaN    0.4218       NaN
   NaN    0.9706    0.8003       NaN    0.9157       NaN
```

Now you want to copy columns 2,3 into one matrix and column 5 into another. One approach is to first find the columns that contain only NaNs. You could do something like this:

```
ind = all(isnan(h),1)

ind =

 1     0     0     1     0     1
```

`isnan` returns an array of 1s and 0s where the 1s indicates where the NaNs are. `all(...,1)` returns the column indices where all the rows are NaNs. `ind` contains the flags that you want. To save each chunk of data individually, you can use a simple `for` loop. Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
j = 1;
k = 1;
x = nan(3,1); %temporary matrix to store numerical values
c = cell(2,1); %cell array to store the chunks of data individually
               %if you can predict how many elements `c` should have, then
               %you can pre-allocate appropriately.

for i=1:length(ind)    
    %loop through all the columns

    if ind(i) == 1  
        %if we encounter a flag and 'x' has data, dump 'x' into 'c{k}',
        %reset 'x' and continue.

        if ~all(isnan(x))
            c{k} = x; 
            k = k+1;
        end

        %reset x
        x = nan(3,1);
        j=1;
        continue
    end


    x(:,j) = h(:,i);
    j = j+1;

    %catch data at the end, if last column of h does not contain all NaNs
    if i==length(ind)
        c{k} = x;
    end

end
```

Your data chunks are stored as matrixes in a cell array:

```
c{1}

ans =

    0.9649    0.9572
    0.1576    0.4854
    0.9706    0.8003

c{2}

ans =

    0.1419
    0.4218
    0.9157
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the sort of thing I was looking for. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what kind of output you want, but here is a way to get rid of the NaN elements:

Let's consider this matrix:

```
A =

   NaN     1     2   NaN     3     4   NaN
   NaN     5     6   NaN     7     8   NaN
   NaN     9    10   NaN    11    12   NaN
```

Then using the `find` command, we can get the columns in which all the elements are NaN (as you stated in your question):

```
[~ ,col] = find(isnan(A))

col =

     1
     1
     1
     4
     4
     4
     7
     7
     7
```

Then we can delete them from A to form a new matrix:

```
A(:,col) = []

A =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12
```

Is this what you had in mind? If not please be more specific. Thanks!